# Print the clicked button's text tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *    

def command(d):
   print(d)

a = Tk()
b = []

for c in range(0, 5):
    b.append(Button(a, text=c, command=lambda: command(c)))
    b[c].pack()

a.mainloop()
```

When running the script, the buttons all print 4, whereas I want them to print the number shown on them. How can you do this?

I am using Python 3.4

Comment: Is your for loop correctly indented in your actual code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, there are a couple of things wrong here. First of all, your `for` loop needs to be indented four spaces like this:

```
for c in range(0, 5):
    b.append(Button(a, text=c, command=lambda: command(c))
    b[c].pack()
```

If you don't do that, then the value of `c` will be 4 for the rest of the script because that is the value of `c` for the last iteration of `range(0, 5)`.

The reason that your buttons are always printing 4 is because the variable `c` is evaluated when the callback is called, not when you assign the callback to the button. A simple way to avoid this problem is to initialize the lambda function with the current value of `c` using a dummy variable (we'll call it `j`) like this: `lambda j=c: command(j)`. Putting this together, you should have something like this :

```
from tkinter import *    

def command(d):
   print(d)

a = Tk()
b = []

for c in range(0, 5):
    x = Button(a, text=c, command=lambda j=c: command(j))
    x.pack()
    b.append(x)

a.mainloop()
```

I changed the way you packed the button because I think it's far more readable, but the end result should be the same.

Comment: `x = Button().pack()` will assign `None` to `x` because `pack()` returns `None`. You need `x = Button() ; x.pack()`

Comment: Additionally you can use `print(b[d].cget('text'))` if using the list is preferred . Since the button objects are appended to a list you can use that to get the text from them.